# Does the Scavenger perk give you extra grenades?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In Modern Warfare 3, does the Scavenger perk give you grenades from dead players? I was wondering if it did for those players who haven't used their grenades. I assume when you scavenge, you get only ammo that the dead player did not use.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't make sense to limit the scavenge to only un-used ammo since it's unlikely everyone is using the same loadout as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to, but **not** in [Modern Warfare 3](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Scavenger_%28perk%29#Call_of_Duty:_Modern_Warfare_3).

> Unlike previous games, Scavenger no longer replenishes Lethal equipment like Frags and Semtex or Tactical equipment like Stuns and Flashbangs. However, Throwing knives can be resupplied.